# Heroku and default database setting

Tags: heroku, migration

I've just deployed a commit to Heroku which adds a `portfolio` field to my `photos` table. I have set `default => true` on this. Here is an abbreviated look at my schema.rb:

```
  create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "portfolio",          :default => true
  end
```

This worked fine in development and changed all the current photos to have a default value of true for `portfolio`. So I deployed the updates to Heroku, ran `heroku rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart`. It migrated just fine, but all the images have `NULL` as their default for `portfolio`. Does anyone know how to get Heroku to change the default value for this in the database? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that migration you are only setting a new default on that column, and that default only applies to new rows, not pre-existing ones which already have a value of NULL.

Like you say, you need to retrospectively set your default into older records as part of your migration:

```
Photo.update_all :portfolio => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `Photo.update_all ["portfolio = ?", true]` to my migration and re-migrating.